# Disable Chrome dialog "Failed to load extension from" using Selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am getting a dialog box while stating chrome driver stating "Failed to load unpacked extension". I am using below code to launch chrome driver, but still getting dialog.

```
        let options = new chrome.Options();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--disable-useAutomationExtension");
        driver = new webdriver.Builder()
            .setChromeOptions(options)
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .build();
        let url = $('#URL').val().trim();
        driver.get(url);
```

[image]

Comment: @DebanjanB the questions suggested are answered for selenium binding for JAVA. I am trying to find the javascript alternatives to achieve the same thing

Comment: Irrespective of the binding art _Java_ / _Python_  / _Javascript_, chrome switches are always the same.

Comment: @DebajanB even I think so, but the above commands are not working for me. I have tried similar things in Java by using the command options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false); but I am unable to find the javascript alternative for this. If you know please share it with me

Comment: I am also facing same issue